# Load XML data into text fields, in Cocos2D Mac

Tags: xml, cocos2d-iphone

I've been playing with XML, going through some tutorials, but my need is specific.  Imagine you have a CCLabel, and you want to load data into it from an XML file.  So on scene x, you load the data from the relevant part of the XML.  For example ,imagine you feed in the page number based up the scene.

Has anyone got any examples, or can anyone point me to anything I should read?

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

For the reading of XML, take a look at the [NSXMLParser](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/XMLParsing/XMLParsing.html) guide. It is up to you to manage the structure of the XML, but essentially, as you recieve read events from the parser, it should be trivial for you to use the text it reads.

Assuming your XML file looks something like:

```
<scene id=1>
  <label id=1 text="Label Text" />
</scene>
<scene id=2>
  <label id=2 text="Scene 2 Text" />
</scene>
```

You have a couple of choices - you can either parse the file each time the scene loads, ignoring everything other than the internals of id=x (where x is some kind of scene reference relating to id), or you can load the entire xml at application start and store it some kind of structure. I'd prefer the first option.

As a basic example (which is still better explained in the documentation I linked to), your element reading function might do this:

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict {

  if ( [elementName isEqualToString:@"label"]) {
    //attributeDict contains the attributes of the element,
    //in your case, "text" is one of the keys, and "Label Text" would be the value
    //this would pass the specific label text from the xml file to a function in your scene
    [scene someFunctionForPopulatingLabel:[attributeDict objectForKey:@"text"]];
  }

}
```